# Copy view in Resource

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want a copy view in Resource similar to create/edit/show. On clicking copy, it should pre-fill form with values and then save should create a new entity( Similar to Edit but with POST instead of PUT).

I attempted to accomplish using customRoute where I created a Link in the ListView and able to render form but not able to prefill form.

How should I fill the values ?

Comment: Where should the values be prefilled from?

Comment: From the list view, if i pick up an item and click on copy button, it should prefill with existing values of that item. Similar to edit but this works more like a clone.